# Can't export textures of a Sketchfab model

Tags: texturing, export, file-format

I'm a blender beginner and since days I can't find a solution to my problem:

I bought a Sketchfab model only available in .fbx format (made with UE) with all textures in another folder. I'm using Blender v 3.2. When I import my fbx and want to assign the texture everything seems fine on the renderer, the texture is well applied on my object but when I want to export it: .fbx export with copy, .glb with automatic export images, .gltf with textures and bin , even .obj , my model is  exported with no texture at all, sometimes only on some small part of it. This is what I already tried:

- search missing file , found the texture, principled BSDF , assigned to the object in edit mode, base color = Texture image and path to the file (png). Texture seems ok on screen but can't export it with texture in whatever format file I choose.
- manually create a new material to the object : same :BSDF principled, texture image in color base and path to the file, Assign to the object in edit mode, application of the texture is fine however still impossible to export it.
- Try to convert original .fbx with converter in other format and then imported it in Blender and try to add texture to the converted file, still same issue when export...
- Try Eeve , Cycles, All...
- Try to replace principled BSDF to Diffuse BSDF... Still no export of textures...

Everything seems fine in shading ,everything is well selected and linked however still no export with textures. I have to precise this is a texture already baked by the creator, what did I forgot? What could be the issue? I just want to attach the original textures to the 3d model and use it with Mixamo to use it on a React app.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but unfortunately it is very complex for a web dev and it demands too much time to get it. In conclusion  I downloaded UE and recreate the 3d model with its texture from the original .fbx Sketchfab model , exported from UE as .glb with textures , imported the .glb into Blender, unpacked the ressources and reattach textures in shading and finally , exported as .fbx and magic happened my .fbx has its textures , a little bit darker but it will do the work!